# How to write .htaccess file for a php file which exist in a directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a file named as **test.php** in a directory named as **onlinetest** as shown in image. I want to rewrite my url **/onlinetest/test.php?name=test1** to **/onlinetest/test1**. Please suggest .htaccess file for this. My .htaccess file is at root follder

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following rule to your htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^onlinetest/test1/?$ /onlinetest/test.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

This will rewrite `/onlinetest/test1/` to `/onlinetest/test.php?name=test1`